# List all files for two dates range using Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, centos

Currently We are using below command to list files with specific date.Below the command list the files for date 2022-01-10 only. But I want to list the file with date range.For Example I need to list the files with date 2022-01-09 and 2022-01-10.Could you please help how to list the files with dates 2022-01-09 and 2022-01-10?

```
ls -tr /mnt/Logs/2022-01-10*
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below command is working for me.

ls -tr /mnt/Logs/2022-01-09*  2>/dev/null || true && ls -tr /mnt/Logs/2022-01-10*  2>/dev/null